# Хранение данных Mac OS X на Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Добрый день.

Помогите разобраться с хранением данных. Недавно я начал писать на objective-c под mac os x, в программе мне надо хранить данные, примерно 500-2000 пар ключ-значение. Как я понял, существует 3 распространенных способа хранения данных на mac os x: plist, core data и sqlite.

Что такое plist и sqlite я знаю, но я так и не понял по прочтении нескольких статей, как устроена core data. Может  кто подскажет статьи, которые можно почитать, где сравнивается функциональность, производительность и все остальное для этих трех систем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data - это разновидность ORM. Прослойка для базы, не важно для какой. Таким образом ты работаешь с объектами, а на самом деле объекты это записи в БД.

Много статьей на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136319/).
Погугли вот эту книжечку - [Pro Core Data for iOS](http://www.amazon.com/Core-Second-Edition-Professional-Apress/dp/1430236566/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1353065964&sr=8-3&keywords=core+data+ios+5). Будешь монстрегом в этом деле.

Comment: спасибо, теперь не стыковки в голове начали улягаться.

Answer (score 2):

http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4227074